# xcode using wrong node.js version

Tags: javascript, node.js, xcode, react-native, nvm

I am new to React Native. I used `react-native init XXX` to create a new project. When launch the xcodeproj, I got an error saying:

```
  const setupEnvScript = /^win/.test(process.platform)
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/allanhahaha/Documents/Seat/getseat/SeatApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:214:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/allanhahaha/Documents/Seat/getseat/SeatApp/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

According to my research, this is a node.js version issue: I should have use v.4.0+.

I am using NVM to manage my node.js versions. In **regular terminal window**, I have this:

```
$ node --version
v5.1.0
```

but in xcode when it run the start shell script, I saw it is using a different version, `v0.10.40`, and xcode doesn't know about `nvm` command either..

**The question is, how should I configure my Mac so the xcode can pick up the same version that I set with nvm?**

Thank you!

---

**Update**: I tried to `source` my `~/.bash_profile` in the shell script executed by xcode, but still not solving the problem.

Comment: Did you see this issue? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3974

Comment: Hi Allan, can you show us what's in your bash_profile, at least the part concerning nvm?
Also do you normally use iTerm or Terminal?

Comment: @ColinRamsay Hi thanks for the comment, I just tried with `. ~\.bash_profile` and it worked...

Comment: @Almouro thank you for the comment, please see the reply above

Comment: You can add the solution as an answer below then accept it yourself to mark this question closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding `. ~\.bash_profile` to the top of shell script.

Answer (score 17):

The problem seems to occur when you have installed react-native-cli with the wrong Node (and thus npm) version.

First shut down xcode and let's make sure that there is no old node processes running, I'm not sure if this is necessary but it is good to make sure:

```
$ ps -e|grep node
$ kill {process number(s) here}
```

Then set the default nvm node version to the one you want to use, for example:

```
$ nvm alias default 6.6.0
```

Then restart your terminal and make sure that the node version is now the one you want by default:

```
$ node -v
v6.6.0
```

Now reinstall react-native-cli with the new node version active (it affects the npm version):

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Now running `$ react-native run-ios` should run xcode with the proper version! (If it doesn't, make sure to restart your terminal/xcode and try again).

Comment: Checking the default fixed my Xcode error - `nvm alias default 8`

Comment: `nvm alias default stable` Did the trick for me since my stable is set to 10. I didn't have to restart xcode or anything, just ran the command and built without issue.

Comment: Best answer here - gives a likely reason for the problem and some sensible steps to address it

Answer (score 7):

Add your node path to Build Phases / Bundle React Native Code and images settings

[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2kY0.png)

Comment: Instead of hardcoding path, I simply assigned NODE_BINARY to nvm which node

Answer (score 7):

I resolved by adding `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to the top of the shell script in Build Phases

Answer (score 4):

For me, adding this to `/etc/profile` or to `~/.profile` worked:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

The reason this is necessary is because XCode uses `/bin/sh` by default and it loads the profiles from the files I specified.

Note: altering `/etc/profile` requires you to use `sudo`. Not sure if this is even possible on MacOS X 10.15 Catalina since I believe they made the system directories to be read-only, no matter what. But if you are able to set it here, this will make it work for any user who has nvm installed.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as this is the top result in Google while searching for this error, the following is the only thing that worked for me.

I had to uninstall node (that was previously installed with the pkg from the Node website), uninstall nvm and reinstall node with Brew.

[Link](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/issues/141) for more information.