# react-native run-ios packager build error - AwesomeProject quick start

Tags: react-native

**The problem**

Open react native issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6203)

I have researched this error extensively (~ 2days dev time) but somehow still no resolution - I have run previous React Native setups fine and thought [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3983) might resolve as a final step (see the end of issue). 
In short, when I run `react-native run-ios` from example "AwesomeProject" directory I get the below error in the React Packager launchPackager.command window.

> ~/AwesomeProject2/node_modules/react-native/packager ~
>   /Users/alexanderhandy/AwesomeProject2/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:74
>
> const setupEnvScript = /^win/.test(process.platform)

**SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.**

```
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

**My setup**

- Macbook Pro 2012 - OS X 10.11 El Capitan
- Xcode (v7.2.1)
- Node (v5.7.0) and NVM (0.31.0)
- React Native (v0.20.0)

**Steps**

- Upgraded laptop to El Capitan (as per version above) - hadn't used much for last 6 months so was coming back to run some setup
- Attempted react native setup and got an error running homebrew when tried to install. Found some unexpected changes to many files when ran git status -- so went into the relevant usr/local homebrew directory and ran `git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master`
- Updated Xcode to over v7 (as per version above)
- Installed nvm and latest node to address error warning from Node - note: for some reason have to run `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` in terminal to get nvm working, when I don't v5.7.0 becomes v0.12.4. I have double-checked node is v5.7.0 when error runs
- Finally got through to actually building an app when ran `react-native init AwesomeProject` which completed but hanged for like 10 mins
- Ran `react-native run-ios` and got error and tried to add `source ~/.bash_profile` to `node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh` as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3983)
- Considered going back to Ionic so went through their setup again and that wouldn't work either
- Tried not to throw my laptop out the window

Comment: @raju-gujarati can you detail more about why you've added a bounty to this? What is your current set up? Are you using RN version 0.20 as referenced in the question?

Comment: My setup



Macbook Pro 2012 - OS X 10.12.6 Sierra
Xcode (v8.3)
Node (v8.4.0) and NVM (0.31.0)
React Native (v0.47.0)

Comment: usually  it  takes for a few minutes to build react-packager . But for my case, it takes infinitely long. I don't know what is going on

Comment: Why are you using such an old react-native package? Have you tried upgrading it? Sorry just see this was already fixed

Comment: This might help you to solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431161/690771

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when creating my project from `react-native init` command. What I did to get a successful build was do `npm install babel` and then finally do `react-native run-ios`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is the issue of Community CLI 
kindly add it properly else remove it from your package.json and run your project from xcode it would help
(https://github.com/react-native-community/cli)

when you start a react native project with react-native init MyProject it doesn't add few things globally so we use npx react-native init MyProject.