# Point xcode to correct node version

Tags: node.js, xcode, bash, react-native, nvm

I usually do not have any issues with `nvm`, but a React Native / Xcode project is failing to build because it's trying to use Node v4.4.3.

My `nvm ls` looks like this:

```
   v5.11.0
   v5.11.1
   v6.1.0
   v6.9.5
   v6.11.5
-> v8.7.0
   v10.1.0
   system
```

When I type `nvm use system` and `node -v` it prints `4.4.3`, so I suppose that's where Xcode is getting `4.4.3` from.

But when I type `nvm alias system 8.7.0` (attempting to alias the system to 8.7.0), it prints `system -> 8.7.0 (-> v8.7.0)` and `node -v` still returns `4.4.3`.
I also tried `nvm install 8.7.0 --reinstall-packages-from=node`, but that didn't really seem to do anything to help the cause.

I probably had node installed with `brew` at one point, but believe I've installed it because `brew node -v` returns `Error: Unknown command: node Error: Kernel.exit`.

Wondering if anyone can point me in the correct direction!

Comment: `nvm alias default 8.7.0` should work.

Comment: It does, I don't have any issues with node from the terminal, just Xcode. It's picking up the 'system' version for some reason and I do not know how to change that.

Comment: Similar issue was discussed in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035421/xcode-using-wrong-node-js-version

Comment: ah ... sorry, misunderstood.   Well, fwiw, i dont use exCode for anything but playing certificates anymore.  Got AppCode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` at the top of the shell script in Build Phases did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11298299/8723007

I also installed node with brew at some point which I just forgot about it because I also use nvm.

:facepalm:

Try `$ brew upgrade node` in Terminal and if that doesn't work trying installing node with homebrew anyway. You should get the system version to be the most up to date. As of rn that's version 11.